# vb.Net timespan calculation

Tags: vb.net, date, format, timespan

I can calculate the timespan in vb.net using the given code

```
    Dim dtStartDate As Date = "17/12/2032"
    Dim iNumberOfDays As Integer
    Dim tsTimeSpan As TimeSpan
    tsTimeSpan = Now.Subtract(dtStartDate)
    iNumberOfDays = tsTimeSpan.Days   'Where iNumberOfDays is the result of the timespan
```

It works perfectly when my computers time format is

> **dd-MMM-yy** (which is found in Control Panel> Date and Time> Change date and Time> Change Calendar Settings> Date Formats.

If I change the computer Date Format to something like this **MM/dd/yy**, my application gives error in the line

> Dim dtStartDate As Date = "17/12/2032"

The error is "Conversion from string "17/12/2032" to type date is not valid.

I need to calculate the timespan in all date format. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use date literals instead, they are culture independent. See [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> You must enclose a Date literal within number signs (# #). You must
>   specify the date value in the format M/d/yyyy... This requirement is independent of your locale and your computer's date and time format settings.

So you can write like this:

```
Dim dtStartDate As Date = #12/17/2032#
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be setting the date using a string literal like that, since the date string will be parsed differently depending on the current culture (as you have discovered).  If it must be a string, you could get around it by using the `DateTime.ParseExact` method:

```
Dim start As Date = Date.ParseExact("17/12/2032", "dd/MM/yyyy)
```

However, if it doesn't need to be a string, I'd recommend using the `DateTime` constructor to pass the individual parameters as separate integer literals:

```
Dim start As New Date(2032, 12, 17)
```

Once you have the start date, you can calculate like this:

```
Dim span As TimeSpan = Date.Now - start
Dim days As Integer = span.Days
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting from a string to a DateTime is a feature that's specific to VB.NET, you couldn't write this code in any other common .NET language.  Nor would it compile in VB.NET if Option Strict On is in effect, such a conversion is too error prone.  Well, you found out why.

Use either of the following solutions instead:

```
 Dim dtStartDate As Date = New DateTime(2032, 12, 17)
```

or if you are stuck with a string:

```
 Dim dtStartDate As Date = DateTime.Parse("17/12/2032", _
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat)
```

With the option you need to keep in mind of adjusting the CultureInfo to match the format of the input string.